# SynchronizationAttribute.SUPPORTED creates synchronization content

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization

According to [article](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx) class below is not thread safe:

I have code which gets into lock while according to my understanding has different synchronization content:

```
[Synchronization]
public class Deadlock : ContextBoundObject
{
  public DeadLock Other;
  public void Demo() { Thread.Sleep (1000); Other.Hello(); }
  void Hello()       { Console.WriteLine ("hello");        }
}

public class Test
{
  static void Main()
  {
    Deadlock dead1 = new Deadlock();
    Deadlock dead2 = new Deadlock();
    dead1.Other = dead2;
    dead2.Other = dead1;
    new Thread (dead1.Demo).Start();
    dead2.Demo();
  }
}
```

It does and it is fine. But I decided to play with synchronization attributes by setting:

```
[Synchronization(SynchronizationAttribute.SUPPORTED)]
```

`SUPPORTED` means :

> Joins the existing synchronization context if instantiated from
>   another synchronized object, otherwise remains unsynchronized

Since console application has no synchronization content I expect both object will have no synchronization object and should not get into deadlock. But I still have deadlock. Why?

Further have removed `[Synchronization]` attribute at all. Still have deadlock. What influence makes `[Synchronization]` attribute to object?

Comment: you will get stackoverlfow exception soon if you run code for long ...are you getting that ??...you are creating circular dependency

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Both with SUPPORTED and without `[Synchronization]` I have no deadlocks.

Comment: I don't get overflow since timeout is too long. But got idea and ready to accept answer.

Comment: @vico note that you will not get stack overflow here no matter how long you wait. It's quite strange to accept answer which does not answer you question at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are creating circular dependency between thread , that might lead you to stackoverflow exception , as you are not catching excpetion here you are might not able to view it. I suggest you make use of `UnObservedExcpetion` handler that will give you excpetion or try to handle excpetion in that same function by putting `try, catch`   block.

To avoid this kind of situation you better make use of [`AutoResetEvent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx). below is sample code for the same.

```
public class MyThreadTest
{
    static readonly AutoResetEvent thread1Step = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    static readonly AutoResetEvent thread2Step = new AutoResetEvent(true);

    void DisplayThread1()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            thread2Step.WaitOne(); 
            Console.WriteLine("Display Thread 1");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            thread1Step.Set();
        }
    }

    void DisplayThread2()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            thread1Step.WaitOne(); 
            Console.WriteLine("Display Thread 2");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            thread2Step.Set();
        }
    }

    void CreateThreads()
    {
        // construct two threads for our demonstration;
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DisplayThread1));
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DisplayThread2));

        // start them
        thread1.Start();
        thread2.Start();
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        MyThreadTest StartMultiThreads = new MyThreadTest();
        StartMultiThreads.CreateThreads();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this answer is related to question, or why it is accepted. There are no "circular dependency between thread" in provided code and no stack overflow exception is possible.

Comment: @Evk - I am not sure about StackOverflowException but there is circular depedancy as , this lines dead1.Other = dead2;
    dead2.Other = dead1; in this two object storing reference of each other , that create circular dependacy between thread

Comment: But that's perfectly normal and does not create any problems in provided code, it's just used to simulate deadlock conditions. And question is about `[Synchronization]` attribute and how it works, but you don't mention this attribute at all in your answer.

Comment: @Evk - last line of question Further have removed [Synchronization] attribute at all. Still have deadlock. What influence makes [Synchronization] attribute to object?

Comment: @Evk - and there is no need of Synchronization thats what i think if you go for AutoEvent

Comment: Well if OP is satisfied with this "answer", why should I bother indeed.